# After adding jquery CDN link to my code, contact us "submit" button stop working

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-modal, contacts

I added a "contact us" form to a working website.

When I tried it, I noticed that the submit button was not working. I removed the jquery CDN link from the code and after that, the submit button started to work and emails are  now sending smoothly.

Can anyone suggest a solution to keep the jquery link and the submit button working properly ?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" /> <br />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea> <br />
    <input type="button" name=" onclick=" myFunction() " value="Submit form"> </fieldset>
</form>

(...)

<script>
    function myFunction() { document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code? Also, where in your code did you put the jquery script tag?

Comment: <form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
     <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
       <br />
       <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
       <br />
       <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
       <br />
       <input type="button" name=" onclick="myFunction()"  value="Submit form">
     </fieldset>
   </form>

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>

Comment: I have put the jquery link at the bottom

Comment: there is probably another mistake. you should see an error in the console. Also my advice, change button's type submit, you dont need onclick declaration in this case

Comment: I've noticed a typo error : a missing ", just corrected it...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that's a typo error, look at your code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm"> <fieldset> <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" /> <br /> <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /> <br /> <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" /> <br /> <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" /> <br /> <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea> <br /> <input type="button" name=" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form"> </fieldset> </form>
```

There is a missing quotation mark ", just after `name="`:

```
<input type="button" name=" onclick=" myFunction() " value="Submit form">
```

So here is your corrected code.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" /> <br />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea> <br />
    <input type="button" name="" onclick=" myFunction() " value="Submit form"> </fieldset>
</form>
```

Always double-check your code, and work on clean-formatted code, it will help you to catch such mistakes.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying with different ways before posting here. I have added the quotation but it's still not working.

Comment: Form works properly wothout jqeuery CDN link . After adding the CDN link it stop working